# Multiple data query with LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a function to get data from my database with join on it. I want to take data from different tables, how can I achieve this? I want to take "libelle_motif" which is from the table "motif_deplacement"

My function right now:

```
    public static List<personne> getPersonne_Deplacement(int numDeplacement)
    {
        List<personne> desP = new List<personne>();

        var query = (from Per in db.personne.ToList()
                     join Dep in db.deplacement_personne.ToList() on Per.num_personne equals Dep.num_personne
                     join Mot in db.motif_deplacement.ToList() on Dep.id_motif equals Mot.id_motif
                     where Dep.id_deplacement == numDeplacement
                     select new personne
                     {

                         nom_personne = Per.nom_personne,
                         num_personne = Per.num_personne,
                         ref_personne = Per.ref_personne,
                         libelle_motif = Mot.libelle_motif,
               });

        desP = query.ToList();
        return desP;
    }
```

And this is how my database looks like :

[image: database]

Comment: `I want to take data from different tables` <= what do you mean by this specifically? Please include an [mvce]  that includes the expected model. Also you are calling `ToList` on your `DbSet`s inside the linq query, do not do that.

Comment: Why are you doing `ToList()` on each DbEntity?

Comment: @Igor : I have data from "personne" I want "nom_personne", "num_personne", "ref_personne" and I also want data from "motif_deplacement", which is "libelle_motif". Then I put all the data I got in a DataGridView

Comment: @FortyTwo : I do not know any other way to manage this exception ... :  The entity or complex type 'anthobot_frediModel.personne' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Comment: You will have to create a new class which will act as the model with the properties you want. Construct one of those in your `select` based on the included relationships. It much easier to manage this query if you model your relationships in your EF entities as opposed to writing out join statements in every query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create a new class which will act as the model with the properties you want. Construct one of those in your `select` based on the included relationships.

Also it much easier to manage this query if you model your relationships in your EF entities as opposed to writing out join statements in every query.

Also notice that I removed all the calls to `ToList`. Your previous code was materializing all entities from each table and then joining and filtering in memory which is extremely inefficient.

```
public static List<SomeModel> getPersonne_Deplacement(int numDeplacement)
{
    var query = from Per in db.personne
                join Dep in db.deplacement_personne on Per.num_personne equals Dep.num_personne
                join Mot in db.motif_deplacement on Dep.id_motif equals Mot.id_motif
                where Dep.id_deplacement == numDeplacement
                select new SomeModel
                {
                    nom_personne = Per.nom_personne,
                    num_personne = Per.num_personne,
                    ref_personne = Per.ref_personne,
                    libelle_motif = Mot.libelle_motif,
                };
    return query.ToList();
}
```

*SomeModel.cs*

```
public class SomeModel 
{
    public string nom_personne {get;set;}
    public string num_personne {get;set;}
    public string ref_personne {get;set;}
    public string libelle_motif {get;set;}
    // add additional properties as needed
}
```

Comment: It worked perfectly! I didn't know that it was a good way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if my answer is related to your question. But why don't you use `.Include()`

Ex:

```
var result  = db.personne.Include(x => x.deplacement_personne).ThenInclude(x => x.motif_deplacement)
```

It will give you this structure:

**obj personne** { nom_personne, ... , **obj deplacement_personne** { ... , obj **motif_deplacement** }

You can also select any cols with `.Select()` , or filter it with `.Where()`.

Comment: Could you please give me a full example? Or more precise! I tried the way you said but it didn't work... I'm not used with LINQ I'm probably not doing it correctly